# IOS ARC: Unable to use #define constant directly

Tags: ios, constants

I have a constant in my MyClass.m file named:

```
#define kUDUserHistory              @"kUDUserHistory";
```

With no-ARC I was able to use it directly but now I have to copy it in second variable and then use it. If I try to use it directly in ARC it shows an error *'Expected Expression'*.
**no-ARC**

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:kUDUserHistory];
```

**ARC**

```
NSString *key = kUDUserHistory;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:key];
```

**My specific Question are:**

- Whay I am not able to use constant directly in this case?
- What is the best approach to manage constants especially in ARC?

Comment: there is nothing to do with arc and non arc, your constant declaration contains a semicolon, probably that causes the issue.

Comment: Midhun MP is correct.  There is no way your “no-ARC” code compiled if you defined `kUDUserHistory` that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#define kUDUserHistory              @"kUDUserHistory";
```

Should be:

```
#define kUDUserHistory              @"kUDUserHistory"
```

For your answer:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"kUDUserHistory";];
```

Passing it first to an `NSString`:

```
NSString *key = @"kUDUserHistory";;
```

That's why it works.

Comment: You are right, removing semicolon solved the problem. But I wonder, why it works when we copy it in second variable?

Comment: @MuhammadNabeelArif because then it expands to `var = @"string";;` and an empty statement is valid, just not within an expression. But couldn't you just learn C properly before trying to write iOS apps?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

in .h file

extern NSString * const kUDUserHistory;

in .m file

NSString * const kUDUserHistory = @"kUDUserHistory";